# chilkat - problems - sql server - download and unzip in memory without any zip file created

Tags: sql-server, zip, chilkat

I'm testing the chilkat example code: (SQL Server) Download a Zip from a URL and OpenFromMemory. (No .zip fie is created) / https://www.example-code.com/sql/zip_openFromMemory.asp . But I only get an errormessage telling me:

```
  Failed to find end-of-central-directory-record.
  Failed to get central dir locations.
```

Does anyone get any solutions to this problem?

```
full ChilkatLog:
  OpenFromMemory:
    DllDate: Oct 28 2019
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.80
    UnlockPrefix: XXXXXXXXXXX
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: ActiveX / x64
    VerboseLogging: 0
    Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.
    oemCodePage: 850
    openFromMemData:
      Failed to find end-of-central-directory-record.
      Failed to get central dir locations.
    --openFromMemData
    Failed.
  --OpenFromMemory
--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the example to avoid the problem.  Also, it should perform better because it won't try to pass the actual binary data across COM boundaries.
Instead, it just uses the Chilkat BinData object. (We pass the reference to the BinData object instead of the data itself.)

Please go to https://www.example-code.com/sql/zip_openFromMemory.asp  to see the changes.  (Refresh the page if needed.)

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chilkat has responded to my support inquiry and made changes to the example script!

Thanks for the quick response!